# Probability - defective boxes

Tags: probability

Out of 12 boxes, 2 were defective. If you randomly select two of the 12 boxes, what is the probability that one of them is defective? Would the probability be 1/12=0,08? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\binom{12}{2} = 66$ ways to choose the two boxes randomly, all equally likely. We have to pick one non-defective one and one defective one in $10\times 2= 20$ ways. So the asked-for probability is $\frac{20}{66}= \frac{10}{33}$.

Alternatively, we could compute $$P(\text{box 1 defective and box 2 OK})= P(\text{box 1 defective})P(\text{box 2 OK}|\text{box 1 defective})= \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{10}{11}$$ (the second draw is from $11$ remaining boxes, with $1$ defective box left)

and $$P(\text{box 1 OK and box 2 defective})=P(\text{box 1 OK})P(\text{box 2 defective}|\text{box 1 OK})= \frac{10}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{11}$$

(the second draw is from $11$ boxes of which $2$ are defective).

And add them to get the same result. The first way scales better with more draws, I think, and is a special case of the hypergeometric distribution.
But the second one is easier to come up with, maybe.